# Place product_id into a price range

Tags: sql, presto

I would like to add for a given product_id a price range, in 500 increments. For example a product with the price of 450 should have the price range of 500 and a product with a price 2450 should have the price range of 2000.

**Main table**

```
product_id       price

32828            2593
23224            456
34344            1000
58283            2420
43585            550
```

**Output table**

```
product_id       price    price_range

32828            2593     3000   
23224            456      500    
34344            1000     1000
58283            2420     2000
43585            550      600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use case when for manage the range as you prefer

```
  select  case  when price between 0 and 500  then  500 
                when price between 501 and  600  then 600 
                when price between 601 and  1500  then 1000
                when price between 1501 and 2500 then 2000
                END  range
```